# How to generate the fields by selecting the dropdown values?

Tags: javascript, php

I had created the dropdown list with fields Labs,Paharmacy,Gym,Food.When I select the Lab from dropdown list it has generate the new field as "name".
When I select the pharmacy field it has to show the upload button field.Please suggest me how to do this.

My form

```
   <form action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" id="quickservice" method="post">
 <div class="fieldset">
<ul class="form-list">
 <li>
            <label for="Servicetype" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Service Type') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <select name="servicetype" class="input-text required-entry validate-select" style="width: 150px;" />
                                    <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('--Please Select--')?></option>
                                    <option value="Lab"><?php echo $this->__('Lab')?></option>
                                    <option value="Hospital"><?php echo $this->__('Hospital')?></option>
                                    <option value="Food"><?php echo $this->__('Food')?></option>
                                    <option value="Gym"><?php echo $this->__('Gym')?></option>
                                    <option value="Physio"><?php echo $this->__('Physio')?></option>
                                    <option value="Nurse"><?php echo $this->__('Nurse')?></option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

            </li>
</ul>
<div class="button">
    <p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
    <button id= "submit"  type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?>" name="send" id="send2"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?></span></span></button>
</div>
  </div>
     </form>
```

Comment: Either you need javascript to do it in same page or you need to submit the form everytime to do it if you want only with php

Comment: when I submit it has to send a mail.But when I select any one from dropdown it has to show the new text field.

Comment: Then you need to use JQuery or javascript to achieve it, PHP is server side scripting that is executed before your page generates

Comment: How to use javascript to generate fields by selecting the dropdown list.Can you please suggest me.

Comment: @MyWay Please suggest me It is very important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show/hide some particular field on selecting an option and you don't want the page to refresh, you should use JavaScript code so for example if you want to show the upload field on selecting "Lab" value you could do it like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <script>
        function showHidden(elem){
           if(elem.value == 'Lab')
              document.getElementById('fileToUpload').style.display = "block";
            else
              document.getElementById('fileToUpload').style.display = "none";
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" id="quickservice" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <ul class="form-list">
            <li>
            <label for="Servicetype" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Service Type') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <select id='servicetype'   onchange="showHidden(this)" name="servicetype" class="input-text required-entry validate-select" style="width: 150px;" />
                            <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('--Please Select--')?></option>
                            <option value="Lab" id='lab'><?php echo $this->__('Lab')?></option>
                            <option value="Hospital"><?php echo $this->__('Hospital')?></option>
                            <option value="Food"><?php echo $this->__('Food')?></option>
                            <option value="Gym"><?php echo $this->__('Gym')?></option>
                            <option value="Physio"><?php echo $this->__('Physio')?></option>
                            <option value="Nurse"><?php echo $this->__('Nurse')?></option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="fileToUpload" style='display: none;'>
            <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" />
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
            <button id= "submit"  type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?>" name="send" id="send2"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?></span></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

and if you want to show/hide more fields, you can use the same logic!

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <script>
        function showHidden(elem){
           if(elem.value == 'Lab')
           {
              document.getElementById('fileToUpload').style.display = "block";
              document.getElementById('city_name').style.display = "none";
           }
           else if(elem.value == 'Hospital')
           {
              document.getElementById('city_name').style.display = "block";
              document.getElementById('fileToUpload').style.display = "none";
           }
           else
           {
              document.getElementById('fileToUpload').style.display = "none";
              document.getElementById('city_name').style.display = "none";
           }
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" id="quickservice" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <ul class="form-list">
            <li>
            <label for="Servicetype" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Service Type') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <select id='servicetype'   onchange="showHidden(this)" name="servicetype" class="input-text required-entry validate-select" style="width: 150px;" />
                            <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('--Please Select--')?></option>
                            <option value="Lab" id='lab'><?php echo $this->__('Lab')?></option>
                            <option value="Hospital"><?php echo $this->__('Hospital')?></option>
                            <option value="Food"><?php echo $this->__('Food')?></option>
                            <option value="Gym"><?php echo $this->__('Gym')?></option>
                            <option value="Physio"><?php echo $this->__('Physio')?></option>
                            <option value="Nurse"><?php echo $this->__('Nurse')?></option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="fileToUpload" style='display: none;'>
            <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" />
        </div>
        <div id="city_name" style='display: none;'>
            <input type="text" name="city" />
            <input type="text" name="name" />
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
            <button id= "submit"  type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?>" name="send" id="send2"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?></span></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Can't we do in javacsript as jquery will not work for us.

Comment: I edited my post for pure JavaScript ... Good Luck ;) @Mouni

Comment: Ok by selecting the hospital it has to add anew text fields as Name,City.Can you please change for it

Comment: @Mouni As you can see, it is easy to do so, you can follow the same logic for your further improvments.

Comment: How can I make it as required fileds?

Comment: @Mouni Bring in your  class="required" with them, i think that will solve your problem.

Comment: Ok but it is showing in row form and the name is not displaying before the text fields.

Comment: City and Name are different fields and I need to add some more text fields for Hospital.Is it possible in the same way.

Comment: @Mouni Yes add all the fields you need in between the city_name div, and it must work properly :)

Comment: @Mouni and you can use <label></label> to label your field in any way you desire.

Comment: Ok.How I need to send an email with the attachment when I browse the file how to get the id for the fileToupload.Please suggest me

Comment: I need to add the new email field under pharmacy with upload button.Please suggest me

Comment: as you previously done, there is a hidden DIV get visible after selecting lab "the div with fileToUpload ID", you just need to add a input field for entering Email. @Mouni

Comment: Ok.For food and nurse also I need to add in the same way.But how to write for javascript is getting confusion.Please suggest me.